# Using Python's requests lib throwing ProxyError

Tags: python, python-requests

I am still new to python and can't figure out how to handle this error and what to do with it to avoid it.

When I use `requests.get('http://www.baidu.com')`

```
    import requests
    header = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36'}
    h=requests.get('http://www.baidu.com',headers=header)
    print h.text
```

It throws a `ProxyError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/freedomcoder/Code/Python/rexx/rexx.py", line 8, in <module>
    h = requests.get('http://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3050',headers=header)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 596, in send
   r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 485, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='107.160.9.10', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: http://www.baidu.com/ (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x02EE4170>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10061] ',)))
```

But when I use `requests.get('https://www.baidu.com')`, it returns the correct page. I don't know why this is the case.

Comment: I just run your code and it's ok.
I think you should remove the header.

Comment: but it still doesn't work.  :(  
Should I reinstall the system？？？@giaosudau

Answer (score 11):

I deal with the problem.

just add proxies={'http':'','https':''}

for example:

```
h=requests.get('http://www.baidu.com', proxies={'http':'','https':''})
```

Comment: bro. I was dying because of this for more than an hour. thanks.

Comment: what a shame, I spent hours trying to solve this proxies issue

Comment: I wasted so much of my time before I found this. @freedomcoder you are a life saver!!

Answer (score -2):

When I tested your code, it  seems to work.

The issue may be a network connection error as others have stated.

One way to verify the issue via cli (the connection should open, like in this example the soconnection opened successfully ...)

```
$ telnet baidu.com 80 
Trying 220.181.57.217...
Connected to baidu.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Comment: the issue:  HTTPConnectionPool(host='107.160.9.10', port=80)                                         I find the host is my vps's ip address. I don't know how to deal with it.......